# basic routing - how to create a link_to path from match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

Ok, say you have this:

`match "tutor_appointments/new_appt" => "tutor_appointments#new_appt"`

How do I create a `link_to` path from it?

Would it be something like this: (it doesn't work, btw)

```
<%= link_to "New Appointments", controller:tutor_appointments, method:new_appt %>
```

I'm always confused on routing stuff when it comes to figuring out how to do `link_to` link.

I do understand that `tutor_appointments` is the controller and `new_appt` is the method.

Comment: You can always just write the path into the link to, eg `link_to "Here", "/tutor_appointments/new_appt"`

Comment: @MaxWilliams, thanks for letting me know of this option too! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you would *name* the route:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

And then you can refer to the route by that name.

eg. if you had:

```
match "tutor_appointments/new_appt" => "tutor_appointments#new_appt", as: 'new_appointment'
```

Then you could do:

```
link_to 'New Appointments', new_appointment_path
```

However, in this case it sounds like what you actually want is *resource routing*:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web

And you want a 'new' action for your 'tutor_appointments' resource.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the naming option. Will do that in future. However, I'm a tad confused about the second part of your answer, ie, resource routing. What did you mean by the last part? `new_appt` is a method/action, not as in new, but as a method per se. Apologies if I'm not getting what you mean.

Comment: If you read through the docs I linked about resource routing (which is very common in Rails), it talks about seven standard actions for a resource - index, new, create, show, edit, update, and destroy. `new_appt` sounds a lot like you want to create a new appointment - which would directly and easily correlate to the new action in a TutorAppointments controller if you were using resourceful routing.

Comment: hey, you know the `new_appointment_path`? When I tried it, I got a totally different page. When I tried to just use `new_appointment` alone, it would come up with a `NameError`

Comment: You must already have a route named `new_appointment` then. Run `rake routes` in your terminal to see what has that name.

Comment: I figured that. I don't want to run rakes to be honest, there are way too many routes in this files. So, I just tried something like `blah_blah` for as. Trust me, there can't be any other routes with that. I still get this: `undefined local variable or method `blah_blah'`

Comment: I would strongly recommend checking out where it's coming from - your routes file may already have something like `resources :appointments` in it (which would generate a `new_appointment_path`). The `_path` suffix is important - you have to include that.

Comment: I'm super confused about this. See, your path generates this route: `http://localhost:3000/tutor_appointments/new_appt`. The above answer generates this route: `http://localhost:3000/tutor_appointments?method=new_appt`, and they both go to different pages.

Comment: because `method` isn't the right parameter name - it should be `action`.

Comment: you're right! when I changed it from method, to action, it went to the same page as your link. Thank you so much for pointing that out. Also appreciate your constant answering to my queries even though I chose the other answer. It's gracious of you to do so.

Comment: can I ask one more dumb question? why is it important to add `_path` suffix?

Comment: because a named route will actually generate two helper methods - one with `_path` and one with `_url`. The `_url` variant is a fully qualified URL including protocol, hostname, port, etc.

Comment: thank you. This has been interesting! Appreciate it.

Comment: BTW, you say you don't want to run `rake routes` because you have too many routes: presumably you mean it will take to long to visually pick through them.  Do you know about `grep`?  It's a handy filtering tool.  Try `rake routes | grep new_appointment`